# VueJS: dynamic class name inside style tags

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a VueJS application which contains some [Materializecss](https://materializecss.com/modals.html) modals, all wrapped within single page components. Due to the nature of the application I have to assign dynamic unique IDs to each modal. Below is a snippet:

```
<template>
    <div :id="modal_id" :class="'modal '+modal_id">
        <div class="modal-content">
            .... stuff here
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Exit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style type="text/css" scoped>
    .modal {
        width: 90% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }

    .modal_id 
    {
        background-color: black;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    import pdf from 'vue-pdf'

    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                modal_id: 'ViewPdf_'+this.$root.g(),    // this.$root.g() returns a unique integer          
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

My question is if it's possible to use Vue to modify the custom class name from within `<style></style>` tags to match the class name generated when component is mounted. If not, what workarounds I could use?

```
<style type="text/css" scoped>
    .modal {
        width: 90% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }

    .modal_id  // <--- I wish this class name was the same with value of this.modal_id
    {
        background-color: black;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the CSS is all contained in your Vue component, you could just produce the style information in your component rather than trying to match up the css selector based on the DOM id.

Specifically, instead of doing this:
`<div :id="modal_id" :class="'modal '+modal_id">`

Do this:

`<div :id="modal_id" :style="modalStyle">`

and then within your component, have a computed property for the style, using the guidelines at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles

For example:

```
computed: {
  modalStyle: function () {
   return {backgroundColor: 'black'};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a computed property that will react to changes in modal_id and calculate a class name that you want to attach to particular modal.

```
<template>
    <div :id="modal_id" :class="className">
        ...
    </div>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {             
            }
        },
    computed: {
        className: function () {
            if (this.modal_id === <your modal_id1>) return 'class1';
            else if (this.modal_id === <your modal_id2>) return 'class2';
        },
        modal_id: function () {
            return 'ViewPdf_'+this.$root.g()
        }
    }
    }
</script>
<style>
  .class1{}
  .class2{}
</style>
```

the modal_id also should be a computed property if you want to make it dynamic.

Comment: I don't understand. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: your answer would be more constructive if you provided some material or code sample to back up your claim

Comment: If they are random then how do you know what class you want to use? This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: This is what I was asking: if there is possible to bind the class name from `<style></style>` tags to the auto generated ID

Comment: But what do you want to achieve this way? Why do you need a dynamic class name if it will always style the same way? Why can't you apply static class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can edit the css property name with javascript if you use an external css file. Here is a simple example in pure javascript that shows how I change the name of the css name, thereby placing its style on the second paragraph.

```js
//the index of the stylesheet based on load order
var cssIndex = 0;
var cssRules = (document.all) ? 'rules' : 'cssRules';

function changeClass() {
    for (i = 0, len = document.styleSheets[cssIndex][cssRules].length; i < len; i++) {
        if (document.styleSheets[cssIndex][cssRules][i].selectorText === ".text") {
            document.styleSheets[cssIndex][cssRules][i].selectorText = ".text2";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.text {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='changeClass()'> Change css property class name </button>
<p id="1" class="text">This is text class</p>
<p id="2" class="text2"> This is text2 class</p>
```

I hope you can apply it in your Vue code.